# how to match values in sql ?

Tags: sql, vb.net

i have a 4 columns in my table..

```
digit1 digit2 digit3 amount
     1      2      3      1
     2      2      2      1  
     2      1      3      1
     3      2      1      1
```

and i want to group them if the row has the same digit value..and the output would be like this :

```
digit1 digit2 digit3 amount
     1      2      3      3 
     2      2      2      1
```

sorry for this noob question though..i'm stuck with this thing since last night..tnx in advance

Comment: group on same which digit? you have digit1 , 2 ,3 ?

Comment: which DBMS are you using? MS SQL Server/MySQL/Oracle?

Comment: if a row contains the same digit..like (1,2,3) & (3,2,1) & (2,1,3) can be group for they got the same set of digit..

Comment: im using MS SQL Server sir..

Comment: i make +1 for the hard question

Comment: @HadiHassan u sir is like an angel from the heaven's above :D

Comment: @yoyieyoyie thank you :) for both the answer and compliments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here a solution

if all digits has the same set of numbers ( 2,1,3) ,(3,2,1),...etc, this means they have same factorial

example: 2*1*3=3*2*1 ... etc

**NOTE**: this solution works for any digits different than zero (Factorial rule)

steps of solution

1. make multiplication and summation for each row
2. make partition based on the multiplication and summation and name it [part]
3. take the records that only appear once => [part]=1
4. count the records

here the solution

```
with fact
as(
select Id,digit1,digit2,digit3,digit1*digit2*digit3 as [mult],digit1+digit2+digit3 as [sum]
from Data),part as(
  select Id,digit1,digit2,digit3,[mult],[sum],row_number() over(partition by [mult],[sum] order by [mult],[sum]) as [Part]
  from fact
  )
select Id,digit1,digit2,digit3,(select count(*) 
                                 from fact f where f.[mult]=p.[mult] and f.[sum]=p.[sum]) as amount
from part p
where part=1
```

and here a correct result [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/14f19/6)

hope it will help you

Comment: ooh..yeah ! the factorial thing..my brain did not tell me that earlier..damn u brain..! tnx sir..a many tnx !

Comment: smart idea +1 from me

Comment: @yoyieyoyie you didn't mark as answer, is there any weakness in my solution?

Comment: @yoyieyoyie just one only

Comment: @yoyieyoyie after thinking, if you take set 6,1,1 it will count as 4 occurance since 6*1*1 = 3*2*1, so my solution is not complete

Comment: @yoyieyoyie i edited the solution to make it correct and modified the demo also

Answer (score 1):

```
please try this one i did it in oracle but its simple sql so it will too work on your DBMS

select digit1,digit2,digit3,(select sum(amount) from expdha 
                             where digit2<>digit1+1 and  digit3<>digit2+1) amount 
 from expdha  
       where digit2=digit1+1 and digit3=digit2+1
       group by digit1,digit2,digit3
  union
       select digit1,digit2,digit3,amount from expdha 
       where digit1=digit2 and  digit2=digit3;
```

where expdha is your table ,if you need explanation then i can explain it .

Answer (score 1):

Use `Case Statement` to get the column in order then using `Group by` Clause you get the result. Try this.

```
SELECT col1,col2,col3,Sum(amount) As Sum_Amount
FROM  (SELECT CASE WHEN digit1 > digit2 AND digit1 > digit3 THEN digit1 
                   WHEN digit2 > digit1 AND digit2 > digit3 THEN digit2
                   ELSE digit3
              END col1,
              CASE WHEN ( digit1 > digit2 OR digit1 > digit3 ) AND ( digit1 < digit3 OR digit1 < digit2 ) THEN digit1
                   WHEN ( digit2 > digit1 OR digit2 > digit3 ) AND ( digit2 < digit3 OR digit2 < digit1 ) THEN digit2
                ELSE digit3
              END col2,
              CASE
                WHEN digit1 < digit2 AND digit1 < digit3 THEN digit1
                WHEN digit2 < digit1 AND digit2 < digit3 THEN digit2
                ELSE digit3
              END col3,
              *
       FROM   #test) a
GROUP  BY col1,col2,col3
```